# Compare strings to see if they are identical

Tags: jquery, string, loops, compare

I would like to loop through a set of strings and see if they are all identical to one another. If all of the strings being looped through are identical, I would like to run one function. If they are not, run another function.

```
$(".variationPrice").each(function(){
    var price = $(this).text();
        if(price == price){
             allMatch();
        } else{
             notMatch();
        }
});
```

Another words, if we had the following data, it would run `allMatch()`:
$55, $55, $55

If we had the following data, it would run `noMatch()`:
$55, $45, $55

The above code does not work but acts as a starting place.  In the above code, price would always match price.  I need to figure out a way to store the first price in a variable and compare all results after to the initial. What is a good way of comparing strings via jquery / javascript?

**UPDATE**
One idea is to push all into an array and then see if there are duplicates within the array like so:

```
var array1=[2,2,1,2,2,2];
function checkForDuplicates(arr){
var x = arr[0];
for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(x!=arr[i]){return 'at least one duplicate found'}
    }
return 'no duplicates found';
}
```

Comment: Store all values in an array and compare them to `array[0]`?

Comment: see update above, how does this look?

Comment: It looks good, I assume the array will be dynamically formed by the strings correct?

Comment: Well, assuming both methods work the same, my guess would be to check efficiency by capturing the time() before execution and after, then comparing and find out on avg which is faster. Otherwise it sounds like a coin toss to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with your initial code you'll just need some variables available from outside the each() scope. This code should do the trick.

```
var allMatch = true;
var price;
$(".variationPrice").each(function(){
    if (price === undefined) {
        price = $(this).text();
    }
    if (price != $(this).text()){
        allMatch = false;
        return false; // No need to check the rest of the array..
    }
});

if (allMatch) {
    allMatch();
} else {
    notMatch();
}
```

Optimized as suggested by comments.

Comment: I thinking about that too, I like this as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This makes complete sense

Comment: if (price != $(this).text()){
        allMatch = false;  return false;
}  This will break the each loop.  No need to continue checking the remaining items.

Comment: That's a good observation. I hadn't thought about optimizing too heavily.